# Apple Enterprise program for In House paid app

Tags: app-store, in-house-distribution

Is it possible to use the Enterprise program to distribute for people in my society private apps, but making them available only as paid application ? 
(They could use their iTunes Account to pay the apps).

Sincerely

Answer (score 1):

You can either distribute an app through the public App Store (standard Apple Developer Program) or internally for your company's employees through the Apple Enterprise Program. For the latter you will need to host your own store.

It's not possible to "mix" those two distribution channels and charge money through iTunes Accounts. You *can* probably integrate your own payment system in your Enterprise app.

Due to recent events, the Apple Enterprise program is getting more attention and it might be harder to distribute apps outside of the terms of use.

> Distribute proprietary, in-house iOS, watchOS, and tvOS apps within your organization. Securely host and deploy apps to your employees' devices.

You might want to check out the full official docs as well as terms of use: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/